# How do you calculate calls per minute in performance test?

Tags: java, performance, performance-testing

In some performance testing reports I see the 'calls per minute' for a certain of API calls. I am not sure if this is an important KPI for measuring a system's resilience.

I am also interested in how to calculate it. I have a small Java web application running on local tomcat. The web application has a controller listening to some http calls. I can fire the calls with RestClient and get some dummy response.

How can I do such calculation with my application?

Comment: you simply count the number of calls for a defined time span. count / time span = calls per minute

Answer (score 1):

You can simply log a timestamp each time your method of interest is called. Then you can use JMeter for load tests. After your test is run, check your log file and count the timestamps in it.

Comment: yeah, timestamps would be great, since you can easily select calls for a specific time span